# Transferring PhD programs after leaving a PhD due to medical issues

Tags: phd, transfer-student

Let's say that I was given unacceptable conditions for returning from medical leave; basically I had to self-fund at least the following year of a physics PhD. Knowing that doing so would result in a financial disaster, I am definitely withdrawing from the program, with the understanding that, if I still wanted to earn a PhD at some point, I would have to transfer.

I could always mention, in an addendum (if there is space for one), medical problems, going to medical services, such as a physician (on-campus and later off-campus) on a regular basis for 75% of the only semester I ended up attending, and leaving school to take better care of myself. (I feel I did what was right from a medical standpoint) But when there is no space for an addendum in an application, I was advised to just drop a line about "personal problems" or "extenuating circumstances" (now resolved) and I am excited to do research again.

And also, I have two publications on file by now, whereas I had none when I applied to PhD programs the first time around (2015 cycle). Because I do not feel my GRE scores were an issue, I do not feel the need to re-take the GRE, general or physics, since they are still valid. But TOEFL, on the other hand, I would have to retake because the scores are no longer valid.

P.S.: I never had Ws before that particular semester, but still somehow ended up with 3.80 for what coursework I still managed to complete. If you need more information about my file or anything else, please, let me know.

How will an early departure from a PhD program (in its early stages) due to medical reasons affect future PhD applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: Now that I modified the above post to reframe the question in more specific terms...

Answer (score 2):

In the public and private R1 universities that I have been in, we do not accept transfers for doctoral students. If you're previously pursued a Master's or taken some graduate courses in the field as part of a doctorate at another institution, you can **petition the department / graduate school for a partial waiver of some of the requirements** *after* you've been accepted and matriculated into the doctoral program.

For example, you might be able to petition out of some of the breadth or depth core course requirements; or request that your years-in-residency be reduced.

Note that because many programs run students in cohort-years, there may be good reasons why you may elect to run the standard pattern even if you've had a waiver of some requirements.